# Divisor on curves, Proposition (II.6.9) from Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have some question related to the proof of Proposition (II.6.9) from  Hartshorne's book:

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism of nonsingular curves over a field $k$. Then for any divisor $D$ on $Y$, $\operatorname{deg}f^*D=\operatorname{deg}f\operatorname{deg}D$.

In proof, let $Q$ be a closed point of $Y$ and let $V=\operatorname{Spec}B$ be an affine open of $Y$ containing $Q$. Let $K(X),K(Y)$ are the function field of$X,Y$, respectively.
Note that if $A$ is the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$, then $f^{-1}(V)=U=\operatorname{Spec}A$. Let $m_Q$ be the maximal ideal of $B$ and $t$ is a local parameter at $Q$ and let $C=A_{m_Q}$. Let $P_i \in X$ be such that $f(P_i)=Q$ and $m_i$ be a maximal ideal of $C$ corresponding to $P_i$.

I have three questions:

1. if $[K(X):K(Y)]=r$, then why $\operatorname{dim}_k(C/tC)=r$?
2. $tC=\cap_i(C_{m_i}\cap C)$?
3. $\operatorname{dim}_k(\mathcal{O}_{P_i}/t\mathcal{O}_{P_i})=v_{P_i}(t)$?, where $v_{P_i}$ is a valuation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it:

1. As stated in the proof, $C$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_Q$-module of rank $r$. Furthermore, $v_Q(t) = 1$, in other words: $t \in m_Q$ and $t \not \in m_Q^2$ and thus $m_Q = (t)$ and  $t\mathcal{O}_Q = m_Q$. This gives $C/tC = (\oplus_{i = 1}^r \mathcal{O}_Q)/(\oplus_{i = 1}^r m_Q) = \oplus_{i = 1}^r (\mathcal{O}_Q/m_Q)$. $\mathcal{O}_Q/m_Q$ is the residue field of $Y$ at $Q$ and since $k$ is algebraically closed, the closed points of $Y$ are rational which means that the residue fields are isomorphic to $k$.
2. You probably mean $tC=\cap_i(tC_{m_i}\cap C)$. I think this is because $t \in m_i$ and thus $t$ is not invertible in $C_{m_i}$ and $tC_{m_i}\cap C = tC$.
3. $t \mathcal{O}_{P_i} = m_i^n$ for $n = v_{P_i}(t)$. Thus $\dim_k(\mathcal{O}_{P_i}/t\mathcal{O}_{P_i}) = n$.

I'm not very certain about these answers and would be grateful for any discussion/correction, since I'm learning the subject myself at the moment.